# How to add several add service like admob,Jumptap etc in one android application?

Tags: android, admob

I am working with an application where i want to add more than one advertise service like Admob, Jumptap or etc in each activity class. There have a solution using skyrocket sdk. But it is autopilot. I just want to add manual for each advertise.

Can any one solve this? I have searched a lot but no luck.

```
[If have any duplicate forgive me]
```

Answer (score 1):

Burstly/ Skyrocket SDK provides bundled SDK to developers for integration ease. Autopilot program ensures your getting the highest yield and manages all billing and payments. You can however select the networks you want to work with. Detailed instructions are shared here - http://support.burstly.com/customer/portal/articles/1078552-what-is-the-network-autopilot-

-Akshay, SDK Developer, InMobi